# A well known definition and its opposite

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

*What is the word, what is its “definition”, and what is its "opposite"?*

[image: puzzle]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first step here is to make sense of the 6 broken text clues. To do this:

> we need to insert particular letters into the right places within the lines to complete the clues.

If we do this correctly, we should produce something that looks a bit like this:

> [image: Completed clues]
>
>  The first 5 clues are all completed by inserting the letters of the word 'INSANITY' at specific fixed locations throughout the clue (the same positions in each clue) and adding spacing as required, meaning they become:
>
>  TOWN ON THE SW CANADIAN COAST (BY SURREY)
>  4TH NATO SIGNAL WORD (TELEPHONY)
>  IN MATHS, "CHANGE" (TO A QTY)
>  AIRLINE BASED IN ATLANTA (DAL ON THE NYSE)
>  FAMILY OF US LAUNCH SYSTEMS (1960-TODAY)
>
>  (Note that in some places our added letters form parts of other letters - e.g. the first 'I' is actually employed as the vertical line of a 'T'...)
>
>  The 5-letter answer to *all* of these clues is **DELTA** ([A Canadian city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta,_British_Columbia); the letter D in the [NATO alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet); the mathematical [difference operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#difference_operator); [Delta Air Lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Air_Lines); the Delta [rocket family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_(rocket_family))).
>
>  The 6th clue is a little different - to complete this one we need to add the letters of INGENUITY, to produce the clue:
>
>  ENDING CHEER; MURDERER; GOOD TRY
>
>  This lists three different descriptions for the word **BRAVO** ('Murderer' likely relates to a famous [murder case](https://www.murderuk.com/florence-bravo.html) in Victorian England.)

Now, how are we supposed to interpret this? Here's one possibility (thanks for the nudge in comments from @juicifer):

> 'The word' here is **INSANITY**, and its 'definition' is the famous phrase, usually attributed to Albert Einstein, that '*Insanity is doing the same thing over and over and expecting different results.*'
>
>  This is brought to life here by the fact that we are adding the same letters in the same places in each line and *always* producing a clue whose answer is the word DELTA!
>
>  However, when it comes to the last line, if we *do something different* - if we 'use our **INGENUITY**' instead - we get something different out of it (to which we are met with a 'BRAVO!'). This plays on the idea that ingenuity is 'the quality of being clever, original, and inventive', and 'the mother of invention'. In this context it is the sought-for 'opposite' of insanity.

Comment: I think you've actually got it: rot13(gur qrsvavgvba bs vafnavgl vf gelvat gur fnzr guvat bire naq bire naq rkcrpgvat qvssrerag erfhygf; vatrahvgl jbhyq gura or gelvat fbzrguvat arj).

Comment: @juicifer I like that - I'll try and rework my answer accordingly. Good thinking, thanks.